# Track external click bounce rate?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website with an external link. I know clicking on this link can be tracked with an event.

I want to find out what the bounce rate is from users who click on the external link - do they return to the site?

Is this possible with Google Analytics - if so, how?

Comment: When you say "return to the site", do you mean come back to your site?  If so that would be a "bounce back rate".   Bounce rate the number of users that view exactly one page on the other site.   Without access to their analytics, you can't answer that question.